# An easy, fun riddle

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> Where a present neigh deceives,
>   and sassy attitude leaves.
>
> A place for money, honey and a foot,
>   Something that opens, closes after input.
>
> At the end of a rock where a group stops,
>   Out from which unexpected wisdom drops.

What am I?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To open is it a

> mouth

Where a present neigh deceives,

> Don't look a gift horse in the mouth - don't say no (horsey neigh) to a present (gift).

and sassy attitude leaves.

> Cheeky words spoken.

A place for money, honey and a foot,

> Put one's money where one's mouth is - backup what is said.
>  Literal honey in mouth - or having a sweet voice.
>  Put your foot in your mouth - say something foolish.

Something that opens, closes after input.

> When eating and drinking.

At the end of a rock where a group stops,

> A end of Ply*mouth* rock where the Mayflower settlers to America landed.

Out from which unexpected wisdom drops.

> Out of the mouths of babes comes truth or wisdom.

Comment: Yep, right on point